# Does $N(Z\cap E') = E'$ and $E'$ perfect implies $N = E'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $Z \le Z(G)$ and $E \le G$ be such that $E'$ is perfect. Also let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $E'$. Does $N(Z\cap E') = E'$ implies $N = E'$?

Comment: Yes.  We have  $[N,E^{\prime}] = [E^{\prime},E^{\prime}] = E^{\prime}$ as $E^{\prime}$ is assumed perfect. But since $N \lhd E^{\prime}$, we have $[N,E^{\prime}] \leq N$. Hence $E^{\prime} \leq N$ and it is assumed that $N \leq E^{\prime}$.

Comment: This does not use that $N(Z\cap E') = E'$; so this is superfluous? EDIT: I see, it is used in establishing $[E', E'] \le [N, E']$! Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does use that, because we are using that $E^{\prime} = N(Z \cap E^{\prime})$ to conclude that $[N,E^{\prime}] = [E^{\prime},E^{\prime}].$